# React Native best practice for positioning, favor percentages and calculations over flex?

Tags: react-native

Coming from a web background it would be considered bad practice to (or not possible) to absolutely position elements and calculate their position in a layout based on the window dimensions. In react-native, we have access to the dimensions of the view port through the `React.Dimensions`.

For example: `let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window')`

I can now use that to center a 100px element by setting it so:

`left: (width/2) - 50`

I much prefer this to using more traditional css techniques. Is there a reason why this shouldn't be done? In a browser the viewport could change if the user resizes the window, but on mobile the viewport size will be static.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my opinion, favor the declarative and dynamic solution when possible (flex over number calculations). But it's a mix of both eventually for a lot of apps.

This [blog post](https://blog.solutotlv.com/size-matters/) compares some layout methods in react native and could help you with better understanding when to use what.